# How does navigation list content retrieval work?

Tags: php, html, css

In one webpage, I have a sidebar whose items have contents of the same nature but different from one another; for example:

```
<ul> 
  <li>Science books</li>
  <li>Fiction books</li>
  <li>History books</li>
</ul>
```

If the user clicks on any of these, a bunch of related books should be shown to him.

My question is: does the developer have to make separate pages for each of these items to show their contents in them or is there a way to create a common page so that once an item is clicked, its content is shown in that common page? (I'm not talking about using JavaScript here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it would be possible with PHP, I would recommend you store your books inside a MYSql Database with a good structure similar to:

```
Type   -   Name           -   Genre
Book   -   My Adventure   -   Science
Book   -   The End        -   History
```

You could add more columns for things like image etc.

Using PHP you could make one page say `books.php` then make the link to it `books.php?type=science`

Then on this php page you could connect to your database and do a query to select all books with the type as science, you can get the variable from the url with `$_GET["type"]`

Something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("ip","user","pw","my_db");
$type=$_GET["type"];
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE genre = $type");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['type'] . " " . $row['name']. " " . $row['genre'];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

In the above example products is the name of your table. The query to get the books is on the `$result` variable, and we are selecting all results from the table products where the genre is your url parameter

Comment: Thanks! That was an extensive answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to create a new page for each, you can simply pass a GET var in your URL and load the results accordingly, for example

```
<a href="page.php?content=books">See Books</a>
```

On `page.php`

Just show the content according to the `$_GET` value for example

```
if(!empty($_GET['content'])) { //Just to make sure content is set and its not empty
   $show_content = $_GET['content']; //books
}

if($show_content == 'books') {
   //Show Books
} elseif($show_content == 'gadgets') {
   //Gadgets Go Here
}
```

> Note: Just make sure you validate and sanitize the `$_GET['content']`
>   value as it can be easily modified by any user.

Answer (score -1):

uyou can do it another way:

```
<ul> 
 <li>Science books
    <ul>
      <li>
         <div class="hidden"> YOUR BOOK CONTENT </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Fiction books</li>
 <li>History books</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does this achieve